# Selecting where first result of related search matches?

Tags: mysql, sql

It's for a filter form. I have two tables like this:
cruise(id, name, [...])
cruise_itineraries(id, cruise_id, port_name, departure_time, [...])

If I were to select all cruises which pass through some port, I'd do something like this:

```
SELECT cruise.* 
FROM cruise, 
     cruise_itineraries 
WHERE cruise_itineraries.cruise_id = cruise.id AND cruise_itineraries.port_name LIKE %?%
```

However, I want to get all cruises which begin it's route in a choosen port, that means this must be the first record from the cruise_itineraries query which matches cruise_id.
I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT cruise.* 
FROM cruise, 
     cruise_itineraries 
WHERE (
        SELECT port_name 
        FROM cruise_itineraries, 
             cruises 
        WHERE cruise_itineraries.cruise_id = cruise.id 
        ORDER BY cruise_itineraries.id ASC LIMIT 1) 
LIKE %?%
```

That means, get the first record of every id and match it with %?%, however I'm not getting any result.

How should I be going about this?

Comment: You need to use a JOIN, and why do you have a cruise.* in your select.

Comment: How would that Join look like? I'm selecting cruise.* because I want all cruise columns.

Comment: you dont need cruise.*. Just * so SELECT *  Can you provide us with an example of both the tables, and an example of the result you want. (what they look like)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want the itinerary where the port has the earliest departure.

```
SELECT cruise.* 
FROM cruise
INNER JOIN cruise_itineraries ci ON
  ci.cruise_id = cruise.id 
  AND ci.port_name LIKE %?%
  AND ci.departure_time = (select min(ci2.departure_time) 
        from cruise_itineraries ci2
        where ci2.cruise_id = ci.cruise_id and ci2.port_name= ci.port_name
        group by ci2.cruise_id, ci2.port_name)
```